# Thunderbird change font like on Windows

Tags: fonts, thunderbird

I was used of fonts in Thunderbird that are thinner and more readable on Windows than in Ubuntu.

How to change Thunderbird fonts under Ubuntu to get same fonts of Thunderbird under Windows like that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get better fonts for Thunderbird 68.4.1 I added a chrome folder in my thunderbird profile folder `/home/myname/.thunderbird/xyzxyz.default-release`.

[image]

You can find this folder zipped here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LdVD4ZI5A19ALWr644cx_53vHwvK5MCA/view?usp=sharing

If it's written in black in the left panel, change the colour from Thunderbird - Themes.

Default font is too condensed, the priority is not the beauty but the readability...